# Any disadvantages to enabling VFP in the Linux Kernel?

Tags: optimization, floating-point, arm, embedded-linux

I am in the process of optimizing an application that runs on an ARM Cortex-A8 Embedded Linux system. The program performs a lot floating point calculations and the VFP was not being used. I had to configure it in the kernel as well as set the appropriate compiler flags. Afterwards, the performance of the application improved significantly.

Is there any disadvantages to enabling the VFP (i.e. CONFIG_VFP=y) in the kernel, power consumption or otherwise?

Comment: Are you enabling VFP in the kernel, or setting a bit in the kernel to enable VFP in a userland process?  If the former, do you really need to run in kernel?  If the later, I’m somewhat surprised it wasn’t already enabled.  Broadly speaking the only real disadvantage of enabling VFP/NEON is that you need to save and restore more state on context switches, but that’s a relatively minor penalty.

Comment: I am talking about enabling it in the kernel to be used by user-space applications. I have not had to do anything additional to enable it in user-land. I am just using the VFP and not NEON. A disadvantage of turning on NEON is that a power domain needs to be turned on, which means more power consumption. However I did not see anything about having to turn on a power domain for the VFP.

Comment: You almost certainly want to be running with NEON enabled as well.  The performance of VFP is nothing terribly special - and if you are willing to live with reduced accuracy in some cases, compilers will generate NEON instructions for single-precision operations.

Comment: @marko: By enabling the VFP, the CPU consumption for the process was cut by a third, so there is a significant improvement. I will look into enabling NEON, but as you mentioned it is not not fully IEEE-754 compliant.

Comment: Neon/VFP use the same registers sets.  Typically, they are saved lazily.  If a task doesn't use them, then they are not stored.  See: [vfp_notifier](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/vfp/vfpmodule.c), which does the heavy lifting for VFP/Neon.  The kernel disables *VFP/Neon* for a task and when an instruction executes, it traps to an *undefined instructions*, the *Neon/VFP* is noted, enabled and code resumes as per normal.  When it is flagged as active, then state is stored.  The only disadvantage is slightly larger page-locked kernel code.

Comment: I guess each *thread_info* will also have some space reserved for the VFP context.  It will always be in an 8K chunk, so it really isn't much of a waste; everything the kernel does is in 4k chunks and the *thread_info* should be 8k with/without VFP; although a kernel processes stack will be slightly smaller.